# WSO2 Carbon studio 1.0.14 does not support enrich fromregistry key

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

I made a sequence in the wso2 esb portal using an envolepe enrich mediator which source was a key from registry. When I moved this code to the eclipse carbon studio 1.0.14 it failed and the enrich mediator instruction got empty.

Is not it supported in this version? Is there a walkaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Carbon Studio 1.0.14 supports both ESB 3.0.1 and ESB 4.0.0. By default is it configured for ESB 3.0.1.

With ESB 3.0.1, there was no option to get the Enrich source from Registry. It was enabled in ESB 4.0.0. Therefore you need to configure Carbon Studio ESB editor for ESB 4.0.0.

You can do it with following steps.

1. Window -> Preferences
2. Expand Carbon Studio and Select ESB.
3. Select ESB 4.0.0 in the ESB Version drop down box and click on Apply and OK.
4. Close your Sequence editor and reopen the Sequence with ESB editor.
5. Then try to re-import the same configuration to Carbon Studio from source view.

Hope this helps!!

Thanks and Regards,

Harshana